# Where does my git question go?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, site-rec

You've got a question about `git`.  Its not uncommon, lots of people have questions about git.  But where should the question be asked?

Answer (score 46):

### Question is about `git` the tool

If you are asking how specific invocations of git such as:

- [How do I edit an incorrect commit message in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-do-i-edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git)
- [How to undo the last Git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)
- [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remote)

These are questions for **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**.  The key point here is you are asking for something to type into the *command line* to do something.

---

### Question is about `git` the workflow

If you are trying to figure out how to use git to do something, understanding the conceptual foundations of git, or how to identify and overcome a problem that you have with the workflow... Questions such as:

- [git for personal (one-man) projects. Overkill?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69308/git-for-personal-one-man-projects-overkill)
- [Why does git use hashes instead of revision numbers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205411/why-does-git-use-hashes-instead-of-revision-numbers)
- [What are the advantages and disadvantages of cryptographically signing commits and tags in Git?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212192/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-cryptographically-signing-commits-a)
- [Using Git in Enterprise environment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96915/using-git-in-enterprise-environment)

These are questions for **[Softwareengineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.  The key point here is the use of the tool in a bigger picture.  It is not one task that the question asks about but the entire workflow.

---

### Question is about `github` the site

There are also questions that are tangentially about git, but are really about github, the website.  Questions such as:

- [Strikethrough with GitHub Markdown](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/strikethrough-with-github-markdown)
- [Can I delete my public GitHub repository?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/can-i-delete-my-public-github-repository)
- [Reference tag from comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52578/reference-tag-from-comment)

These are questions for **[Webapps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.  The key point here is if you are trying to figure out how to get something to work with *github*.  This is about *specifically* github and not about setting up your own git server (thats most likely a Stack Overflow question in the [git-daemon tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-daemon)).

---

### Question is looking for a git client

If you are trying to find a git client that fits some set of features  look at the [Software Recommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) site.

As of this writing, this site is still quite young.  There are very specific requirements to what you need for asking a good question on the site.  However, if you are trying to decide which tool to use and neither [GUI clients](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) from git nor your current IDE's git integration work, this would likely be the best choice.

---

If you have questions about any of the above, feel free to drop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) and ask the question about which Stack Exchange site a question best belongs on.

Comment: I expected an answer like _git away_

Comment: Where do questions like "how to learn C++" fit?

Comment: @BlessedGeek "how to learn XYZ" questions are typically too broad for any Stack Exchange site.  There are textbooks upon textbooks covering the area and then you get into the sub realms of programming languages (embedded vs game vs enterprise). Stack exchange works best when there is a single problem that can be solved in a few paragraphs.  If you can imagine an entire book on the subject, its probably too broad.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: That's answered [in the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Comment: The point about GitHub here is a little off. Firstly, although it's a little controversial, there are many people, me included, who [argue that GitHub questions are generally on-topic on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295378/1709587). Secondly, and importantly, *not all GitHub questions are on-topic on Web Applications*. GitHub, like many online tools for programmers, is made up of both a web application *and* a set of desktop apps and programming tools (`hub`, the SDKs, the desktop clients). Questions about any of the latter are GitHub questions but are off-topic on WebApps.

Comment: @MarkAmery StackOverflow is inconsistent on its treatment of GitHub questions.  Many that deal with non-programming aspects of the site get closed there rather quickly (and ultimately deleted). The questions there are the ones that have still survived. As a static "ask GitHub questions on SO" I feel I would be wrong the vast majority of the time. In particular, none of the questions I link to on WebApps would be on topic on SO. By no means are all questions about some topic on topic on a given SE site. Note that I link to the Webapps help center to help refine this.

Comment: I agree with most of your comment, but personally I would be fine with any of the linked WebApps questions being asked on Stack Overflow, and would vote to reopen or undelete them if they were closed or deleted. Exactly as you say, SO is hugely inconsistent on what to do about GitHub questions; different Meta questions at different times have reached different consensuses, and there's no official line from any mods or staff. I have my view; other people have very different ones.

Comment: @MarkAmery I have very little influence upon Stack Overflow's scope. For users with a question about GitHub, 95% of the time, it is probably a WebApps question. In the 5% of the time it isn't, its a toss up if it will get closed on Stack Overflow or not. I will not recommend a user to post a question on a site where I am fairly certain it will get closed or result in various meta drama. So far, the questions [have migrated to WebApps for github](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+migrated%3Ayes+is%3Aq) have all been well received there.

Comment: So no Git Questions belong on Software Engineering Stack Exchange? Contradicting [this sibling Question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7254/34735)?

Comment: @BasilBourque It turns out Programmers.se = Software Engineering Stack Exchange, so that is not the case. But I was confused at first too.

Comment: Can someone with enough reputation edit "Programmers.SE" in the answer?